# Validación de captcha en php

Tags: php, woocommerce, captcha, recaptcha

Ok, quiero ser directo y detallado en esto, así que no se preocupen. La cuestión es que recientemente descargué un proyecto free source de un e-commerce hecho principalmente en php, lo uso para mi negocio.

El problema actual viene en el registro y el recaptcha, tuve que crear un proyecto en google y ponerle mi key y esas cosas. Bien, lo he conectado correctamente (i guess) la cosa es que al finalizar el formulario de registro y responder "correctamente" el captcha, le doy al submit y manda este mensaje

Al revisar el código y ver cuál es la parte que hace que mande ese mensaje, pues parece ser esto (del archivo register.php):

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

include 'includes/session.php';

if(isset($_POST['signup'])){
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $repassword = $_POST['repassword'];

    $_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstname;
    $_SESSION['lastname'] = $lastname;
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;

    if(!isset($_SESSION['captcha'])){
        require('recaptcha/src/autoload.php');      
        $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha('aqui puse mi key secreta de google recaptcha', new \ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\SocketPost());
        $resp = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

        if (!$resp->isSuccess()){
            $_SESSION['error'] = 'Por favor responder el captcha correctamente'; //aquí es donde ocurre el error
            header('location: signup.php'); 
            exit(); 
        }   
        else{
            $_SESSION['captcha'] = time() + (10*60);
        }

    }
```

Como ven, manda el mensaje de

> "por favor responder el captcha correctamente"

cuando se supone que **ESO HIZO**

Y el código completo del register.php se los pongo aquí por si algo

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

include 'includes/session.php';

if(isset($_POST['signup'])){
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $repassword = $_POST['repassword'];

    $_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstname;
    $_SESSION['lastname'] = $lastname;
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;

    if(!isset($_SESSION['captcha'])){
        require('recaptcha/src/autoload.php');      
        $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha('Aquí puse mi key secreta de google recaptcha', new \ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\SocketPost());
        $resp = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

        if (!$resp->isSuccess()){
            $_SESSION['error'] = 'Por favor responder el captcha correctamente'; //aquí ocurre el problema
            header('location: signup.php'); 
            exit(); 
        }   
        else{
            $_SESSION['captcha'] = time() + (10*60);
        }

    }

    if($password != $repassword){
        $_SESSION['error'] = 'Las contraseñas no coinciden';
        header('location: signup.php');
    }
    else{
        $conn = $pdo->open();

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS numrows FROM users WHERE email=:email");
        $stmt->execute(['email'=>$email]);
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        if($row['numrows'] > 0){
            $_SESSION['error'] = 'Este correo ya está en uso';
            header('location: signup.php');
        }
        else{
            $now = date('Y-m-d');
            $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            //generate code
            $set='123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
            $code=substr(str_shuffle($set), 0, 12);

            try{
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email, password, firstname, lastname, activate_code, created_on) VALUES (:email, :password, :firstname, :lastname, :code, :now)");
                $stmt->execute(['email'=>$email, 'password'=>$password, 'firstname'=>$firstname, 'lastname'=>$lastname, 'code'=>$code, 'now'=>$now]);
                $userid = $conn->lastInsertId();

                $message = "
                    <h2>Gracias por su registro.</h2>
                    <p>Su cuenta:</p>
                    <p>Email: ".$email."</p>
                    <p>Contraseña: ".$_POST['password']."</p>
                    <p>Por favor hacer click en el siguiente enlace para activar su cuenta.</p>
                    <a href='http://localhost/activate.php?code=".$code."&user=".$userid."'>Activar cuenta</a>
                ";

                //Load phpmailer
                require 'vendor/autoload.php';

                $mail = new PHPMailer(true);                             
                try {
                    //Server settings
                    $mail->isSMTP();                                     
                    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                      
                    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
                    $mail->Username = 'anteikustore1@gmail.com';     
                    $mail->Password = 'anteiku123';                    
                    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
                        'ssl' => array(
                        'verify_peer' => false,
                        'verify_peer_name' => false,
                        'allow_self_signed' => true
                        )
                    );                         
                    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                           
                    $mail->Port = 465;                                   

                    $mail->setFrom('anteikustore1@gmail.com');
                    
                    //Recipients
                    $mail->addAddress($email);              
                    $mail->addReplyTo('anteikustore1@gmail.com');
                   
                    //Content
                    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  
                    $mail->Subject = 'Sitio de registro';
                    $mail->Body    = $message;

                    $mail->send();

                    unset($_SESSION['firstname']);
                    unset($_SESSION['lastname']);
                    unset($_SESSION['email']);

                    $_SESSION['success'] = 'Cuenta creada, revisa tu correo para activar cuenta.';
                    header('location: signup.php');

                } 
                catch (Exception $e) {
                    $_SESSION['error'] = 'El correo no pudo ser enviado. Mailer Error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
                    header('location: signup.php');
                }


            }
            catch(PDOException $e){
                $_SESSION['error'] = $e->getMessage();
                header('location: register.php');
            }

            $pdo->close();

        }

    }

}
else{
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'Llenar primero el formulario';
    header('location: signup.php');
} ?>
```

Las solicitudes me las registra en el apartado de admin.
No sé si necesitan el código del signup.php, pero por si algo lo dejo también aquí:

```html
    <?php include 'includes/session.php'; ?>
<?php
  if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    header('location: cart_view.php');
  }

  if(isset($_SESSION['captcha'])){
    $now = time();
    if($now >= $_SESSION['captcha']){
      unset($_SESSION['captcha']);
    }
  }

?>
<?php include 'includes/header.php'; ?>
<body class="hold-transition register-page">
<div class="register-box">
    <?php
      if(isset($_SESSION['error'])){
        echo "
          <div class='callout callout-danger text-center'>
            <p>".$_SESSION['error']."</p> 
          </div>
        ";
        unset($_SESSION['error']);
      }

      if(isset($_SESSION['success'])){
        echo "
          <div class='callout callout-success text-center'>
            <p>".$_SESSION['success']."</p> 
          </div>
        ";
        unset($_SESSION['success']);
      }
    ?>
    <div class="register-box-body">
        <p class="login-box-msg">Registrar un nuevo usuario</p>

        <form action="register.php" method="POST">
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" placeholder="Nombres" value="<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['firstname'])) ? $_SESSION['firstname'] : '' ?>" required>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" placeholder="Apellidos" value="<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['lastname'])) ? $_SESSION['lastname'] : '' ?>"  required>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
          </div>
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['email'])) ? $_SESSION['email'] : '' ?>" required>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="repassword" placeholder="Repetir contraseña" required>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in form-control-feedback"></span>
          </div>
          <?php
            if(!isset($_SESSION['captcha'])){
              echo '
                <di class="form-group" style="width:100%;">
                  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="Aquí puse la otra clave que te dan del recaptcha"></div>
                </di>
              ';
            }
          ?>
          <hr>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" name="signup"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Finalizar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
      <br>
      <a href="login.php">Ya tengo una cuenta de usuario</a><br>
      <a href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Inicio</a>
    </div>
</div>
    
<?php include 'includes/scripts.php' ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Y bueno, eso sería todo, perdonen por saturar con tanto código y texto, pero quería ser detallado con mi problema y además tengo algo de prisa por estrenar mi e-commerce, he intentado borrar esa parte del código para que me mande directo al register.php, me registra el usuario, sin embargo me muestra un error de líneas de php. La versión del recaptcha es 1.1.2 según los archivos que he leído, y no sé si eso cree conflicto con el recaptcha v2 del proyecto que creé en google. Y sí, **buscando me di cuenta que google desactivó esa versión**, pero al parecer leyendo en el proyecto de github aún hay gente que la usa, además ¿por qué me registra solicitudes en la admin. entonces? así que estoy muy confundido y eso me deja en un callejón sin sálida y siento que aquí me pueden proporcionar una ayuda que agradeceré enormemente. Gracias por leer y de nuevo perdonen por tanto texto y las molestias, pero quería ser minucioso explicando el problema. Muchas gracias por su atención.

Answer (score 1):

ya lo arreglé, pero no voy a eliminar el post por ahora, en caso de que alguien llegue a leer esto y le sirva. Lo que hice a continuación fue lo siguiente

Jamás identifiqué por qué me mandaba eso, pero empecé a leer a fondo los archivos de las librerías de recaptcha que tenía instalado y vi que salían de esta web: https://packagist.org/packages/google/recaptcha. Ahí entendí que esto no era la versión del recaptcha, sino de las librerías y que estas son compatibles con recaptcha v2 y v3

Lo que hice simplemente fue reemplazar las librerías, lo mismo hice con el phpmailer, le di acceso a mi correo y listo...
No era nada del otro mundo y yo matándome la cabeza por una tontería...